# Does "Damaged Goods" always refer to psychological or other intangible effects?

Tags: word-usage

My sense is that it never means an actual physical defect as in, "The quarterback's knees were shot -- he could still throw, but he knew that to management he was damaged goods."

Or can it be used in the case of concrete damage to a person's body as the above example?

It seems like for a simple medical issue, the term is too nebulous and indeed would be used when the extent or classification of the problem is not so clearcut, like some psychiatric problem that most people do not fully understand.

Answer (score 2):

Psychological problems may be the more common metaphorical use, but the expression is also used when the problems are physical:

> "Who the hell needs college anyway?"
>
> "That may be your only good option, because of the ankle. If the pros think you're damaged goods, if they don't see something more out of you again this spring, they'll probably back off."
>
> — [Plunking Reggie Jackson](https://books.google.com/books?id=OFGJNWiGmOsC&pg=PA87&dq=%22damaged%20goods%22%20ankle&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVo6_TkeGAAxVVk4kEHThfDxoQ6AF6BAgEEAI)

Answer (score 1):

*damaged goods* refers literally to an item marred or broken in some way during shipping and handling.  The phrase is often used figuratively to refer to a person as if they were a damaged thing, as "damaged merchandise".  The damage can be physical or psychological.

It is a colloquialism and the register is somewhat jocular, though the laughter is often harsh or bitter.

It has nothing to do with imprecise or "nebulous" classification, but with likening a person to defective merchandise. The locution is *reductive*.